# End of line char ($) doesn't work inside square brackets

Tags: regex, grep

Putting `$` inside square brackets doesn't work for grep.

```
~ $ echo -e "hello\nthere" > example.txt
~ $ grep "hello$" example.txt 
hello
~ $ grep "hello[$]" example.txt 
~ $
```

Is this a bug in grep or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Something wrong. `[$]` is a character class of the character `$`. That's what the `[]` are for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what it's supposed to do.

```
[$]
```

...defines a character class that matches one character, `$`.

Thus, this would match a line containing `hello$`.

---

See [the POSIX RE Bracket Expression definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) for the formal specification requiring that this be so. Quoting from that full definition:

> A bracket expression (an expression enclosed in square brackets, "[]" ) is an RE that shall match a single collating element contained in the non-empty set of collating elements represented by the bracket expression.

Thus, any bracket expression matches a single element.

---

Moreover, in [the BRE Anchoring Expression definition:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08)

> 2. A dollar sign ( '$' ) shall be an anchor when used as the last character of an entire BRE. The implementation may treat a dollar sign as an anchor when used as the last character of a subexpression. The dollar sign shall anchor the expression (or optionally subexpression) to the end of the string being matched; the dollar sign can be said to match the end-of-string following the last character.

Thus -- as of BRE, the regexp format which `grep` recognizes by default with no arguments -- if `$` is not at the end of the expression, it is not required to be recognized as an anchor.

Answer (score 10):

If you're trying to match end of line characters or the end of the string, you can use (|) like so "ABC($|\n)".

Answer (score 6):

You can, however, use `$` in a parenthesis grouping, which facilitates the use of `|` (or), which can accomplish the same idea as a square bracket group.

Something like the following might be of interest to you:

```
~ $ cat example.txt 
hello
there
helloa
hellob
helloc

~ $ grep "hello\($\|[ab]\)" example.txt
hello
helloa
hellob
```

Comment: Note from my 2015 answer -- POSIX _allows_ grep to match `$` in the tail position of a subexpression (as you show here), but doesn't _require_ it to do so. Mainstream GNU and BSD implementations definitely support this, but I wouldn't use it in code being written with the expectation that it'll run on random minimalist embedded systems or the like.